# How to show an image on a device without any quality loss

Tags: android, imageview

I have a **320 x 320** image on my server and when I download it and show on my device. Its blurred.

I tried to show it in an ImageView with the below params.

```
 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="320dp"/>
```

**I also tried getting the dp equivalent of 320 px on my device(240 dpi) and reduced the** `layout_height="213dp"`

But still the image is unclear. Where as the image on the server is perfectly clear.

Comment: use property of scale type of image view 
 android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: Check how you are storing image on the server.. are you compressing or using inSampleSize?

Comment: @UsmanKurd If i user `android:scaleType="fitXY" ` The image will lose its aspect ration and looks even worse.

Comment: try to hard code the width and height to Image Size as if you already know the dimension of the image is 320x320

Comment: @UsmanKurd Yeah I tried using `layout_height="320dp"` `layout_width="320dp"` It looks the same(blurred)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to define a value? Try this code:

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. specify image view width and height as wrap content. if it does not work then try 2.
2. Try to use draw9 patch tool to generate equivalent image for image you have stored on server. Then downloaded image will be clear.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that your 320px x 320px image is probably being scaled up to 480px or 640px (depending on the device you have) because you specified 320 **DP**. If you want the image to be 320 DP in the layout then you will have to provide a much higher resolution image that can be scaled down in lower resolution devices.

Comment: Since my device is `240 dpi` it expects a `480 x 480 image` when I set the `width and height to 320 for my imageview`?

Comment: I actually tried setting the imageview width and height as `210dp` assuming that the device will now expect a `320 x 320 image` which I am sending. But it looks the same(blurred).

Comment: Do you need to set the width / height? You can also set `scaleType` to `center` to disable scaling.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: `scaleType="center"` displays a tiny image, which is like `40 x 40` on my device.

Comment: Are you sure your device is only 240 dpi?

Comment: yeah. `540 x 960 pixels, 4.5 inches (~245 ppi pixel density)`